# how to display a pdf file as a download link from mysql without path directing way in php?

Tags: php, html, pdf, mysqli

I tried to display **`pdf`** files from **`mysql`** in the webpage without any path directory. is it possible to do that?

I tried this:

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['download']) ?>" 
    type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

but this shows the pdf file but no download link. i want it present as a link and when i click the link it starts downloading but without no directing path such that path is unknown.

Comment: Does `$row['download']` contain a link to the file or only file name?

Comment: it contains the file i guess. but the pdf displays on my webpage. with  right click and "save as" i can download it.but i don't want that.i just want it as a link

Comment: And you don't want to show the path where file resides?

Comment: You'd need `header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='document.pdf'");` to force download the file

Comment: can u describe in details?

Comment: Why don't you make a PHP file that takes it ID of the file you want to download and return the file data as PDF? That will automatically download it to the user!

Comment: actually i wanted to display a table on the webpage.in one column of the table i would keep the download link of the pdf that stored in mysql database